# Anime involving astronauts training underwater

Tags: planetes

All I can remember from this is that in one episode, they are doing astronaut training. I believe it was underwater and that they have a task to complete in a specific amount of time. I also remember having a part where they are put in groups (in an isolated 'pod') and if one team member quits, the whole group fails. Also, when they are isolated, the examiners start a leak in oxygen so the students lower the temperature and 'hibernate'.

Comment: Any idea of year/decade it's from, art style, etc.?

Comment: I think it's from with the last 10 years, I don't remember it clearly, I wanted to re-watch it but it's been over a year. I  am pretty sure it has only one main character who is a boy

Comment: Also, it kind of reminds me of Space Brothers when they are put in groups in the chambers , except the anime I watched was more intense, also I remember one of their tasks being "put together the model of the spaceship/spaceship engine"

Comment: While Space Brothers does cover two men enrolled in the astronaut program to achieve their aspirations, it isn't what you're looking for. I've seen a bit of Planetes, but I haven't gotten far enough in it to see what you're looking for. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Episode 20 of **[Planetes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetes)** features an isolation test and they have to build a model of the ship that will take them to Jupiter:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Additionally, during that episode, in order to test the isolation adaptability of the candidates, they turned off the oxygen and watched as team after team hit their emergency buttons without having a way to cope

[image]

And the way the main character's team dealt with the issue was turn down the temperature so that they use less oxygen:

[image]

[image]